# Parse: Send Pushes to logged in users only

Tags: parse-platform

I can send push notifications to a specific user using Parse.
But I want the user to receive the notifications, only if he is logged in using ParseUser.logInInBackground
If the user is logged out and a notification sent to him, it should be buffered and then when he logs in again, he shall receive the buffered notifications.

Is it possible to do that with Parse?

Answer (score 1):

You can take care while sending the push, to send to only logged in users. Parse currently has a session's api, which maintains and opens up a session table which contains the logged in users and their installation id's. You can query the session table for the user's to whom you have to send the push, and if they have a session, then you can send the push notification to these users.